# How to scroll horizontally in a page using Robotframework Ride

Tags: python, xpath, robotframework

How to scroll horizontally in a page using Robotframework Ride?

```
div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%
```

If I use Testscroll    0   250, it doesn't scroll horizontally.

Comment: RIDE is an IDE -- you can't scroll web pages with RIDE per se. Are you asking how to use robot framework and the selenium keyword library to scroll a web page?

Comment: yes to scroll the web page horizontally. i am able to scroll the webpage vertically . but not horizontally

Comment: For vertical scroll i use this code.                                                             Test Scroll                                                                                      [Arguments]    ${x_location}    ${y_location}
Execute Javascript    window.scrollTo(${x_location},${y_location})                 so  i call method Test scroll  0    250 for vertically scrolling page          what is the way for scrolling horizontally the web page.

Comment: with the help of jquery i am getting the width of scroll jQuery('.dataTables_scrollBody').width() what is the command for getting the width  . If i give get get length or get value its not retaining the width exactly. the total width is 1126. if  i  give get length it is returning 40.If i get width i will use jQuery('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft(1126) easily.so give idea how to get exact width

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am too having same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am able to scroll a web page horizontally or vertically successfully. Please use Keyword (Execute Javascript)

Syntax

window.scrollTo(xpos, ypos)

Execute Javascript  window.scrollTo(0,5000) 
or 
Execute Javascript window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)

More details may be found on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option is through javascript execution. I just passed by the same problem and all the web pages I found refers to javascript execution.

The best approach I found was:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Scroll Page
    Open Browser    http://demo.mahara.org    firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
    Sleep    5s
    Scroll Page To Location  MyDivID  0    2000

*** Keywords ***
Scroll Page To Location
    [Arguments]   ${id}  ${x_location}    ${y_location}
    Execute JavaScript    document.getElementById('${id}').scrollTo(${x_location},${y_location})
```

[Source Reference](https://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-robot-framework-menu/selenium-robot-framework-python-menu/237-page-scroll-using-robot-framework-python)